# Seek and ye shall find

Tags: riddle, word-property

My first question, and I made this riddle.

> Given a person you do not know, add me and they become more dangerous
>
> Given a rehearsed speech, add me and then put it on a Victrola
>
> Given an extinct bird, add me and it becomes a popular Indonesian treat
>
> Given an eel trap, add me and it becomes a scheme

**What am I?**

I expect this to be answered quickly, but have fun nonetheless!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> The letter **L**

*Given a person you do not know, add me and they become more dangerous*

> STRANGER becomes STRANG**L**ER

*Given a rehearsed speech, add me and then put it on a Victrola*

> I guess this is supposed to be [PATTER](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/patter)<sup>def. 2</sup> becoming P**L**ATTER

*Given an extinct bird, add me and it becomes a popular Indonesian treat*

> DODO becomes [DODO**L**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodol)

Given an eel trap, add me and it becomes a scheme

> [POT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eelpot) becomes P**L**OT

Answer (score 5):

Answer:

> The letter L

person you don't know:

> stranger becomes strangler

Extinct bird:

> Dodo becomes dodol which is a toffee

eel trap:

> Pan to plan?

rehearsed speech:

> Patter to platter.

Couple of them are a stretch.

Comment: I thought of the same thing for the speech, but that word really doesn't mean "rehearsed" at all.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Yeah, way down the list of definitions was to speak or sing rapid-fire words in a theatrical performance. So I went with it lol

Comment: You got 3 out of four! Just need to work out the last one...